# Generating a VS Database Project Snapshot using Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, msbuild, csc

My team currently use a Visual Studio Database project to manage changes to our database, this is a little new to me.

To produce the `dacpac` using this Database project type you right click the project then click `Snapshot Project`.

What I would like to do is script this functionality using Powershell, I have found that using the [SqlPackage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) you can produce a dacpac but this only seems to work against a database in a sqlserver instance.

How can I do the same thing against a project?

I've tried to spy out the command that VS runs as well, which looks like this...

```
#C:\'Program Files (x86)'\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701`,1702`,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /debug:pdbonly /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\Database1.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /warnaserror- /utf8output `"C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework`,Version=v4.5.SqlClrAttributes.cs`"
```

But when I execute it I only get the following and not much else:

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 12.0.30723.0

for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?